# Correct Evaluation of a re-test of Bayesian hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, prior

Given a Bayesian hypothesis email experiment with 2 variants (test 1) with uninformative prior Beta(1,1) that results in a 34.96% Prob(T1 > C) and a identical re-test (test 2) a week later for validation.

My question now is whether it would be better to aggregate the results of test 1 and 2 (both are in the past) with uninformative prior or to use the results of test 1 as prior for test 2. By aggregating, I'm getting a probability of 60.12% (not meeting launch rule), by using the posterior of test 1 as prior for test 2, I'm getting a probability of 66.73% (meeting the launch rule).

Although I'm aware that the statistics are only intended for decisions that are pointing to the future, I'm not yet sure how a re-test can be handled correctly, as the results are already available before the analysis. Would it be better to pretend not knowing the result of test 2 by updating my belief based on test 1 or to treat both tests as one test by increasing the power of my data?

Comment: Are you sure you did your maths right? Aggregating and using old data to define the prior is usually the same thing.

Comment: The algorithm itself should be correct, I'm just unsure on the approach and chosen prior. Let me give the concrete example.